# Why do we say backwards but not forwards

Tags: speech

I have just realized that I've never seen movement descriptor "forward" written with an 's' like backward**s**

Comment: It happens. Both _backward_ and _forward_ can have an optional _-s_, just like [_toward_ and _beside_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/besides.html).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forwards%2Cforward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforwards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforward%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an often-optional "-s" at the end of many English adverbs. [Per wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-s#Etymology_3), here is a list of similar words:

> backwards; downwards; homewards; inwards; outwards; sidewards; skywards; towards; upwards; betides; besides; betimes; sometimes;
>   always; sideways; crossways; anyways; unawares; needs; eftsoons; anyhows; whiles; athwartships; amidships; upstairs; downstairs;
>   eastwards; westwards; southwards; northwards; leewards; forwards; shorewards; landwards; seawards; sternwards; larboards;
>   starboards; ofttimes; evenings; otherwhiles;

Different dialects and different speakers will vary in their usage of this "-s", which is what you're encountering.

Comment: interesting, indeed!